# TpFIBTransaction giving error: Transaction is not active in Delphi XE4 with FIBPlus 7.5

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird, delphi-xe4, fibplus

I am migrating from Delphi 7 to Delphi XE4. With Delphi XE4, I am using FIBPLUS 7.5. Delphi 7 application is running fine but I am getting a runtime error in Delphi XE4:

```
"Project abc.exe raised exception class EFIBClientError with message frmABC.transRead: Transaction not active"
```

PAS File

```
var
    transRead: TpFIBTransaction;
    ...
    ...
    //transRead is used like this
    with TpFIBQuery.Create(Self) do
    begin
      Database := dbMyDB;
      Transaction := transRead;
      SQL.Add ('Select .....');
      ExecQuery;
      Close;
      Free;
    end;    

  DFM File

  object transRead: TpFIBTransaction
    DefaultDatabase = dbMyDB
    TimeoutAction = TARollback
    Left = 192
    Top = 196
  end
```

I have searched all pas and dfm files in entire project. I have not found any statement like this:

```
transRead.Active := True;
```

But I did find following statement at many places:

```
if transRead.Active then
begin
..........
..........
end
```

I have also seen this at some places:

```
transRead.Active := False;
```

Don't we need to activate the transaction? Is it automatically activated? Please suggest me any clue on which should I focus to get rid of this "Transaction is not active" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just set property `AutoReconnect = True` of TFIBDatabase and it worked.

Answer (score 4):

There are two ways: 
1. Start the Transaction before execQuery or
2. Set the optionsfield qoStartTransaction in Options of TpFibQuery like:

```
Options := Options + [qoStartTransaction];
```

Comment: Why the change in the code? Delphi 7 is running fine and I am running same code in Delphi XE4. I don't think there could be any code change.

Comment: @nkp you can always use IFDEF, then the changes will not reflect your delphi 7 app.

Comment: @MatheusFreitas - I have already searched for it. I didn't found any declaration or transaction opening code in $IFDEF.

Comment: @nkp for FIB you can set default Options in the FIB-Ide Tools, maybe these are different in your Setup for Delphi 7 and XE4? These can be the reason for different results

Comment: @Fritzw - Can you elaborate what are FIB-Ide Tools and what setting have to be looked there?

Comment: @nkb There should be a menu-entry in your IDE for FIB. I have no FIB installed anymore so i can not help further, but i think you should start your Transactions every time you need it yourself, so you have the control. And i think you should read the documentation from FIB and Firebird about transactions

Comment: @Fritzw - I have come to this link where StartTransaction is ticked in the screenshot. How can I open this screen here on my system to make this setting? http://www.devrace.com/en/fibplus/articles/4763.php

Comment: @nkb You should install the FIB Tools, and search your source for StartTransaction. You should manage your transactions self and "NOT" depend on a setting elsewhere.